# Does an insecure ftp connection compromise all other data transfers?

Tags: file-upload, ftp

I am not a technical person. My company recently asked me to install FileZilla to transfer files to and from a server in my company. So I installed FileZilla and typed in the credentials my company gave.

Then the following message appeared.

[image: .]

I would like to ask whether the insecure FTP connection only affects the data I send using FileZilla and my computer, and if my other data transferred via ways other than FTP is secure. Is my wifi network and ethernet as secure as the period before I installed FileZilla?

Comment: Does your company require you to use a VPN to connect to their network?  If so, are you enabling the VPN connection before you connect FileZilla to the company's FTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is only for the FTP connection to that server. The warning isn't even about FileZilla, but about the connection between your computer and the server using FTP. You could use another FTP program and have the same problem. You could connect to the server using other, more secure options, and they would be secure.

To use analogy, you could be using sealed letters to communicate with everyone, but to communicate to this server, you need to use a bullhorn. Using the bullhorn is insecure but doesn't expose all the sealed letters you sent.

However, as it says, the credentials will be sent in a way that anyone looking can read it. If you use that password or those credentials in other places, then someone could log in using what they learned.

Comment: so ftp is like http? although ftp is not a secure way to communicate, ftp would not be like virus that contaminates other secure channels of communication like https, etc?(given that one does not use the sensitive info transferred via ftp in other places)

Comment: Correct. It's like the letter/bullhorn analogy. Or the difference between a train in a tunnel (HTTPS) and a road in the open air (FTP). They are completely different modes of "transport" that do not intersect or contaminate each other.